# De Broglie wavelength and wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, wavelength, wave-particle-duality

Is the De Broglie wavelength of a quantum entity same as the wavelength of its wave function?
If yes, why? If no, why? If it is true only under certain circumstances, what are the conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the wave function is a plane wave then it is a De Broglie wave, and its wave length is the same as that of the De Broglie wave. However, wave functions can be very different from plane waves. De Broglie theory was just an early milestone in the development of quantum theory, and today it is primarily of historical interest.

Comment: Could you please explain why that is the case for plane waves?

Comment: This is the case the De Broglie considered. More importantly, you need to be able to define a wave length, which limits the number of possibilities. And a standing wave would have zero momentum. Technically, in 2D *plane wave* is indeed to restrictive as a term, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

It is very different! The wave function is a representation of the probability (only a representation, NOT the probability!) of a particle to exist in a certain position. In other words, it is only a mathematical model to show the probability of the particle's existence on a certain point. While on the other hand, the de Broglie wavelength of the particle is due to the duality of particles.